# Implementation of Google Job Posting

Tags: html, properties, jobs, google-search, posting

I have read through this article: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting#JobPosting-definition and found where the Required Properties are that I will need to add to a job posting. I'm not sure how to actually do this. I saw mention of it being done with JSON but I am unfamiliar with it. Is there a simple way I can use html to add these properties to a job post, such as one that would appear in a blog post of a Wordpress site?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simple way I can use html to add these properties to a job post, such as one that would appear in a blog post of a Wordpress site?

No.

HTML is a document format, it isn't well suited for providing data with the level of structure demanded by this type of problem.

> I saw mention of it being done with JSON but I am unfamiliar with it.

That's the format that the API you want to use expects data to be provided in (it is also the format that the *vast* majority of web services use). You need to get familiar with it.

Read [the website](http://json.org/) and [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159), and find a JSON encoding library for whatever programming language you are using to connect to the Job Posting API (e.g. the [JSON object for JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response Quentin. Unfortunately the client needed something ASAP so I didn't have the time to learn JSON. I did however find a WP plugin that did the trick. It sis called WP Job Management: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/.

Answer (score 0):

Here I implemented for one of my client.

They were running jobs portal website. so i have done job posting schema using json_ld. here is the code i have used inside my page

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "JobPosting",
  "baseSalary": "100000",
  "jobBenefits": "Medical, Life, Dental",
  "datePosted": "2011-10-31",
  "description": "Description: ABC Company Inc. seeks a full-time mid-level software engineer to develop in-house tools.",
  "educationRequirements": "Bachelor's Degree in Computer Science, Information Systems or related fields of study.",
  "employmentType": "Full-time",
  "experienceRequirements": "Minumum 3 years experience as a software engineer",
  "incentiveCompensation": "Performance-based annual bonus plan, project-completion bonuses",
  "industry": "Computer Software",
  "jobLocation": {
    "@type": "Place",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "addressLocality": "Kirkland",
      "addressRegion": "WA"
    }
  },
  "occupationalCategory": "15-1132.00 Software Developers, Application",
  "qualifications": "Ability to work in a team environment with members of varying skill levels. Highly motivated. Learns quickly.",
  "responsibilities": "Design and write specifications for tools for in-house customers Build tools according to specifications",
  "salaryCurrency": "USD",
  "skills": "Web application development using Java/J2EE Web application development using Python or familiarity with dynamic programming languages",
  "specialCommitments": "VeteranCommit",
  "title": "Software Engineer",
  "workHours": "40 hours per week"
}
</script>
```

Here is the one of site that implemented good Scheme Refer : https://allgovernmentjobs.in/ . there you can find the job posting schema.

you can check this url : https://allgovernmentjobs.in/latest-government-jobs into the google structural Data testing Tool : https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/ and fetch the url. You will get the idea about how the code as implemented and it helps for the better results in google search